# Taking picture with LinkSprite JPEG Color Camera

Tags: c#, camera, jpeg, uart

I am using LinkSprite JPEG Color Camera to take picture. I am getting hex values of the picture data as string in C Sharp from UART. User manual of the camera explains the data structure of the picture as starting with hex FFD8 ans ends with FFD9. The values I am getting fits this description. When I save this hex values to a file using ByteWriter but output file is invalid and I can not see the picture.How can I convert these values to JPEG file?

I am using HCS12 Microcontroller based DRAGON trainging board. I am getting camera data via UART. And I am using C to write my code on DRAGON board. Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/dR4BJMBZ

Camera information:
http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10061

User manual:
http://www.linksprite.com/upload/file/1333187137.pdf

My C# code:

http://pastebin.com/WXnTL7jd

Comment: Is this the RAW data? If yes - you will need to demosaic it first to even get an RGB image. JPEG is a little farther away. You will need to provide more info.

Comment: No it is not RAW according to the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olcay Ertaş ,, you are right it is not raw data

My friends and I faced the same problem while working with our camera. Like you we extracted the HEX data using the UART, and like you we didn't see the picture. For us the problem was that using a notepad to save the Hex data will only save it as an ASCII string. (we used notepad to save the raw data)

Here is how we solve it:

1. We used the XVI32 hex-editor program (which is free).
2. Take the hex data and copy it from the FF D8 ... till the FF D9.
3. Use the program to insert the string into a new file.
4. Save the file as a .jpg file.

I hope it works for you as it did with us.

Comment: Thank you very much @Esawi. But I have tried the same method but I have an other problem with the file size. How did you get the file from UART? Can you sen me your code?

Comment: Olcay ,, could you please give me more details about your setup and your problem ? ,, The only problem faced us with size is that we are using the camera with a micorcontroller and the image size was too big for it to handle ,, and so it has to be divided into smaller chunks for the microcontroler to process.

Comment: I have added some information. We have also tried different chunk sizes but still we have a problem with the picture size.

Comment: mmm ... i don't know if you did this or not, but with us the chunks we received from the camera had a suffix string and prefix string that we had to delete before putting the chunks together into one file .. have you done that ??

Comment: No we did not know that. But it is not important anymore. Project due date passed. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: Ahh !! i checked out your camera manual (it's the same as ours) , the suffix and the prefix strings are "76 00 32 00 00" you just need to delete these strings from every chunk before putting them together and i think you will get the picture this time .. 

It s bad luck that your project due date is passed, but you could try it in the future :D .. Good Luck Olcay :)